# How to manually edit my citation and add "references there in"

Tags: citing

I'm using ShareLaTex and i have a citation "(Bleeker,2002 & references there in)" I want to cite like this in my PDF, I tried to search for a package to do this or manually edit `\cite{Bleeker2002}` but couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if you use a citation management package, such as `natbib` or `apacite`.

Comment: As Mico mentioned, more information is needed. But a good guess would be to simply use the postnote for that. As in `\cite[\& references therein]{Bleeker2002}`.

Comment: To get also the brackets you could use `\parencite[\& references therein]{Bleeker2002}` for `biblatex` or using `natbib`: `\citep[\& references therein]{Bleeker2002}`

Comment: @Mico previously i was using package {Chicago} which didnt help me to do what i wanted now i have replaced it by natbib and  used those commands mentioned by others here . Thanks for yours answers.

Comment: @gusbrs - Now that the OP has confirmed that `natbib` is in use, please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Mico, that's done!

Answer (score 2):

There really is no need for extra packages or other tweaks, the postnote of the regular citation commands should be enough. So, with the standard `\cite` you could:

```
\cite[\& references therein]{Bleeker2002}
```

Or, as LukasCB noted, if you also want the parentheses:

```
\citep[\& references therein]{Bleeker2002}
```